# How can I write XML output?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

How can I see the XML output of following C# code? I can see that it uses XElement, but where I can locate the XML file or the output?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XElement doc = new XElement("searchresults"); // root element

    //create 
    XElement result = new XElement("result",
                             new XElement("Resulthead", "AltaVista"),
                             new XElement("ResultURL", "www.altavista.com/"),
                             new XElement("Description", "AltaVista provides the most comprehensive search experience on the Web! ... "),
                             new XElement("DisplayURL", "www.altavista.com/")
                             );
    doc.Add(result);

    //add another search result
    result = new XElement("result",
                             new XElement("Resulthead", "Dogpile Web Search"),
                             new XElement("ResultURL", "www.dogpile.com/"),
                             new XElement("Description", "All the best search engines piled into one. All the best search engines piled into one."),
                             new XElement("DisplayURL", "www.dogpile.com/")
                             );

    doc.Add(result);

    string xmlString = doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it is saving to the disk.  You're just putting it in a String.

Comment: i tried this :

doc.Save(@"D:\VSProjects\SearchEE\SearchEE\bin\Debug\searchresults.xml");

No hope!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your result only exists inside your "xmlString" variable - it's not being written anywhere, neither onto the console / window, nor into a file.

You'll have to add a

```
doc.Save(@"C:\your-xml-file-name.xml");
```

line at the end of your method to save the contents to a file on disk.

Make sure to use a full path, or check in your current directory where the app is running (i.e. in `(yourappname)\bin\debug`, most likely).

Marc

Comment: i put the above code at the end but there is no xml outfile created.

Comment: i tried this there is no files there!

doc.Save(@"D:\VSProjects\SearchEE\SearchEE\bin\Debug\searchresults.xml");

Comment: i am not getting any error ; i do have access to that directory

Comment: This project is at the same location:

D:\VSProjects\SearchEE\SearchEE\bin\Debug

Comment: is there any reference need to create in project ?

Comment: This is last two lines of the code

string xmlString = doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
                        doc.Save(@"D:\VSProjects\SearchEE\SearchEE\bin\Debug\searchresults.xml");

Comment: OK, this is odd - this just works ....... can you check in the debugger that the string "xmlString" contains the correct XML as you'd expect?

Comment: As for reference: since you're using Linq-to-XML, you need `using System.Xml.Linq;` but if you didn't have that, the code wouldn't even compile....

Comment: there is using System.Xml.Linq;, but there is no output in the string

Comment: does the above code works for you, do u did anything extra other than copy pasting  the code in the window?

Comment: only copy&paste into a brand-new Winforms app - no tweaking of any kind.

Comment: This is really really strange, so let's try crazy stuff... Is the Load event hooked up to the `Form1_Load` method you showed? Look it up in the Properties window, click in the little lightning bolt and scroll down to Load. Or, add a button, and place that code into the Click event handler. Run an click the button. Does it work?

Comment: can you try copy&pasting that code into a new winforms app, and also try a different path (e.g. C:\ or something). This is extremely weird......

Answer (score 3):

That code is not writing XML anywhere but memory (the `xmlString` variable).

You could try calling [`XElement.Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360171.aspx) and get it on a file:

```
doc.Save(@"filename.xml");
```

Or use the debugger and look at the variables.

Or, if you prefer, simply put it in a TextBox:

```
textBox.Text = xmlString;
```

Be warned it may not be nicely formatted...

Comment: i put the above code at the end but there is no xml outfile created. 

Like this...........

doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
                        doc.Save(@"searchresults.xml");